# Método POST desde URL en JSF

Tags: jsf, post

Estoy haciendo un proyecto JSF y tengo que tener disponible una ruta en un bean que ejecute un método cuando se acceda a esa ruta mediante petición post, ¿como se podría hacer para hacerle un url mapping al método en cuestión?

```
@ManagedBean
```

@RequestScoped
public class Persona {

```
public Persona(){
    super();
}

private String nombre = "Nombre por defecto";

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

//quiero ejecutar este metodo por post e ir a index.xhtml
public void test(String nuevoNombre){
    this.nombre = nuevoNombre;
}
```

}

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas, JSF funciona haciendo que todas las peticiones a URLs JSF sean procesadas por `FacesServlet`. ¿Puedes explicarte mejor y añadir el código que has probado? Revisa [ask] y [help].

Comment: Necesito tener una url como por ejemplo http://localhost:8080/prueba a la que responda un método que acepte parámetros por post y me redirija a un jsf como por ejemplo index.xhtml, te pongo el bean que tengo de prueba para intentar hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no esta clara la pregunta si ud quiere retornar una url a un cliente REST:

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("login")
public class PersonaWSRest {
    @GET
    @Path("guardar")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public void pru(@QueryParam("num1")int a,@QueryParam("num2")int b) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Desde el servidor....");
        return "url";
    }
}
```

si ud necesita dentro de algun metodo redirigir puede usar:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pagina.xhtml");
```